# AngularJS how return a string instead of Json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I use angularjs to get a string from a web service. This string is actually a base64 pdf file.

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.pdf");
    var content = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return content;
}
```

Angularjs return me a array like this one:

{"0":"\"","1":"J","2":"V","3":"B","4":"E" ...}

But I need a complete string like this : "JVBE..."

I try to find a way to get the complete string instead of array format and I don't find anything.

Do you know how handle this?

Thank you!

Karine

Comment: I don't see any `Angular JS` code here.. either no `Javascript`... It looks like you are mixing `Java & Javascript`. There is no `var` keyword in Java and so no `File.ReadAllBytes()` function in `Javascript`. Your `Get` function must return an error at execution/compilation..

Comment: @Lorenzo, actually it looks like C# code (there is `var` in C#). But you're right anyway, no JS here at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are returning data from .Net MVC's Web API. You can do

```
public object Get(int id)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.pdf");
    var content = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return new {value = content};
}
```

Since a string can't be converted to JSON.

Comment: That give a anonymous return type... Are you sure this is the good way?

Comment: @Karine If that is your C# code of your web API, then the answer is yes.